# Yii2 Select data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

how I can choose columns from relation table ?

```
$orders=Category::find()
->joinWith('posts')
->all();
```

I tried yet

```
$orders=Category::find()
->select('post.*')
->joinWith('posts')
->all()
```

etc, but i gets error:
Getting unknown property: common\models\Category::id_post

```
Excecute Sql statment : SELECT `post`.* FROM `category` LEFT JOIN `post` ON `category`.`id_category` = `post`.`id_categoryFK`
```

but i can't using columns from table post
I would like to write data from the joined tables

Comment: Did you read this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading ?

Comment: Yeah, but i can't understand of which method to use

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a really good explanation in this [Yii2 Wiki Article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/). But I will simplify that article, using your input.

You probably have two models that you want to join: `common\models\Category` and `common\models\Post` with all the attributes matching the ones in the Database. Also, let's say that `Category` **has many** `Post`s associated to it, but a `Post` only **has one** `Category`.

### 1. Define the relations in the Models

First you have to make Yii2 to understand that there is a relation between two Models. Yii2 will do some magic to help you join the tables, but you have to setup the models fist.

#### 1.1 Editing `Category` Model

In `common\models\Category` add the following lines:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Posts::className(), ['category_id' => 'id_categoryFK']);
}
```

#### 1.2 Editing `Post` Model

In `common\models\Post` add the following lines:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Post::className(), ['id_categoryFK' => 'category_id']);
}
```

### 2. Retrieve the data

Now, from any controller you can use it like this:

```
/* Access posts from a category*/
$category = common\models\Category::find()->where(['category_id'=>$category_id])->one();
foreach($category->posts as $post) // iterate over all associated posts of category
{
    $postTitle = $post->title; //access data of Post model
}

/* Access category from post */
$post = common\models\Post::find()->where(['id'=>$post_id])->one();
$categoryName = $post->category->category_name;
```

### 3. Keep learning

As I said in the beginning, this [Yii2 Wiki Article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/) will help you in most of your cases. This other [Yii2 official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html), is very good too.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, now working! Tell me yet, how is difference between method with WithJoin/with and this method?

Comment: Setting those relations in the models tells explicitly to Yii2 how to join those tables. Yii2 by default assumes that foreign keys are named in a specific way, and in your case when joining, Yii2 assumes that your `post` table has a `category_id` attribute as a foreign key to `category` table. But since you named the foreign keys in a different way, Yii2 got confused and throw that error.

Anyway, you can explicitly build a SQL join statement, but it's always better do it "the framework way" :)

Comment: I have one more  question.  My code:

      `$category = Category::find()
            ->select('category.id_category,         post.id_post,post.id_categoryFK')
            ->innerJoinWith('posts')->orderBy('post.id_post')
            ->all();`

This is not a normal array, but object Active Record, so i don't know how this write in loop foreach

Comment: Use `asArray()`. Eg: `$category = Category::find() ->select('category.id_category, post.id_post,post.id_categoryFK') ->innerJoinWith('posts')->orderBy('post.id_post')->asArray()->all();`. Then you can loop with: `foreach($category as $row){ // do something with $row }`